# Django IntegrityError even though I check for existing record

Tags: python, database, django

I have uuid set to be unique in the Model and the following code is supposed to prevent any duplication issues, but if the uuid already exists, it generates an IntegrityError.

It looks like the get returns false even if there is a video object with the requested uuid.
Any idea why this might be happening?

```
try:
    v = Video.objects.get(uuid = video_id)
except Video.DoesNotExist:
    v = Video(uuid = video_id)
    v.save()
```

Comment: Is `uuid` the primary key on the Video object? If it is, try `Video.objects.get(pk=video_id)`. The `pk` is a little trickery to reference the primary key of the table.

Comment: no, its not the primary key, but it is also unique

Answer (score 0):

`IntegrityError` is the expected exception that will be raised when something like a duplicate key occurs. This is how you catch the situation.

What you should focus on is the failing query:

```
v = Video.objects.get(uuid = video_id)
```

If you know for a fact that a Video object does already exist with the `video_id`, then you should check to make sure the type of `video_id` is correct. Aside from that, the rest of the behavior seems expected.

Comment: I've tried this as well, and in this case it generates a DoesNotExist error. I'm completely stumped.

  `try:
   v = Video(uuid = uuid)
  except IntegrityError:
   v = Video.objects.get(uuid = uuid)`

Comment: You should try printing the `video_id` value and `type(video_id)` and confirm it matches the value of the database. Also, from a `python manage.py shell`, are you able to just do a query for the `video_id`?

Comment: Yeah, they all seem to be fine. But the get is not returning anything. Could this somehow be unicode related?

Comment: That would probably depend on the specific database you are using. Is the value of `uuid` something that contains non-ascii characters? What is the value of `video_id`? Are you able to do a successful raw query using your native database client?

Comment: Using MySQL. UUID is just ascii text something like 'sds8sdf-sfdk8sdf-sdfdsl-78sdf8ss'. And yes, I can do a successful raw query. It just doesn't work in the script.

Comment: So you say it works fine when you do `Video.objects.get(uuid = "sds8sdf-sfdk8sdf-sdfdsl-78sdf8ss")` in a shell? Also, when you say the get() doesn't return anything... do you mean it raises an exception, or that it returns None?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right. I'm starting to think there must be some kind of whitespace character issue or with that string. And it raises a DoesNotExist error.